# Can we use a symmetry argument instead of integration in BASIC probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, symmetry

> Suppose $H$ is a random variable with pdf $f_H(h)$.
>
> Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with joint pdf
>
> $$f_{X,Y} = f_H(x) f_H(y)$$
>
> Prove $$P(X \ge Y) = 1/2$$

---

Is it possible to answer the above basic probability question with a symmetry argument?

---

In the following advanced probability questions a symmetry argument is not only possible but also necessary because we don't know if the random variables have pdfs:

[Prove symmetry of probabilities given random variables are iid and have continuous cdf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539690/prove-symmetry-of-probabilities-given-random-variables-are-iid-and-have-continuo)

[Prove independence of events given random variables are iid and have continuous cdf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548257/prove-independence-of-events-given-random-variables-are-iid-and-have-continuous)

[Confusion with real numbers and random variables; Integration and Independence in Williams](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908453/confusion-with-real-numbers-and-random-variables-integration-and-independence-i)

---

Without symmetry argument:

$$P(X \ge Y) = \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{-\infty}^{x} f_H(x)f_H(y) dx dy$$

Let $$u = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f_H(y) dx$$

to get

$$= \int_0^1 u du = 1/2$$

(Side questions: Do we even need $H$? The fact that $X$ and $Y$ have a joint pdf that splits up into a function of $x$ and a function of $Y$ means that the joint pdf splits up into the pdfs of $X$ and $Y$ assuming they exist...do they?)

That's allowed I'm guessing because even if somehow the random variables don't have pdfs (which they always do anyway in basic probability), $X$ and $Y$ together have a joint pdf, which is all we need.

---

**But is there a way to do this in a symmetric way?**

It seems that $X$ and $Y$ are independent because the joint pdf splits up into independent (not in the probability sense) functions of $x$ and $y$:

$$f_X(x) = kf_H(x), f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{k}f_H(y)$$

Am I allowed to say the following?

$$f_X(x) = kf_H(x), f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{k}f_H(y)$$

$$\color{red}{\stackrel{?}{\to}} kf_H(x) = \frac{1}{k}f_H(x)$$

$$\to k = 1$$

$$\to f_X(x) = f_Y(x)$$

I guess that would make sense if $X$ and $Y$ had the same range or something?

Assuming that is allowed, it appears $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

Is there a way to argue that

$$P(X = \max\{X,Y\}) = P(Y = \max\{X,Y\})$$

using basic probability and without integration?

Comment: I would have thought you could say (a) they are independent since you can separate the densities and (b) they are identically distributed; so by symmetry $P(X \gt Y)= P(Y \gt X)$.  Combine this with (c) $P(X=Y)=0$ since they have a density, and you get your result

Comment: @Henry How do you know they are identically distributed? How do know that $$P(X > Y) = P(Y > X)$$? What do you mean by 'symmetry' (in a basic probability sense) ?

Comment: If we do not have prior machinery set up, the symmetry argument takes longer than the integration argument.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah, thanks. Answers to other questions then please?

Comment: @BCLC: You proof that under the given conditions $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution is correct. Maybe one could assert this is the case by symmetry. But there seems no way of avoiding (unless one knows it already) proving that $\Pr(X=Y)=0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry I mean post as answer so I can give you rep hehe

Comment: @BCLC: The remark about needing more machinery is really in the comment category, not in the answer category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the joint probability density function: $f_{X,Y}(x,y) := f_H(x)f_H(y)$ where $f_H$ is itself a probability density function of a continuous random variable.

Then we can find the marginals are both $f_H$. $$\begin{align}f_X(x) =&~ \int_\Bbb R f_H(x)f_H(t)\operatorname d t \\[1ex]=&~ f_H(x) \int_\Bbb R f_H(t)\operatorname d t \\[1ex] =&~ f_H(x)\\[2ex]f_Y(y) = &~ f_H(y) & \textsf{similarly}
\\[2ex]\therefore~ f_{X,Y}(x,y) =& ~ f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)
\end{align}$$

Hence these two random variables have *identical*, *independent*, and *continuous* distributions.